# Making existing token immutable

Tags: spl-token, token, spl-token-program, spl-associated-token-account, spl

How can I change an existing token I created from mutable to immutable? I want to change this on an SPL token would appreciate any help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't provide information about what "mutable" or "immutable" mean. As it's phrased, the question is too vague to answer correctly.

Answer (score 2):

without seeing the token address, i would assume that you can use https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/df3e34156f0f2a90dd962058116782b54367d81c/programs/token-metadata/program/src/processor/metadata/update_metadata_account_v2.rs and pass in `false` for `is_mutable`

Answer (score 0):

Mint account or Token account ? I assume you mean Mint-Account

1. Create a mint account with "null" freeze-authority
2. Mint tokens - increase supply
3. Create an upgrade mint-authority and set that to "null"